# Search inside comma separated values using mysql and php

Tags: php, mysql

My table structure is,

```
ID    NickName    City    LookingFor
------------------------------------
1      First      City1     men
2      Second     City2    Women
3      Third      City3    men,women
4      Fourth     City4    men,women
```

**Case 1:** I want to display person those who are looking for **men and women**. The required output should be,

```
ID    NickName    City    LookingFor
------------------------------------
1      First      City1     men
2      Second     City2    Women
3      Third      City3    men,women
4      Fourth     City4    men,women
```

**Case 2:** I want to display person those who are looking for **men**. The required output should be,

```
ID    NickName    City    LookingFor
------------------------------------
1      First      City1     men
3      Third      City3    men,women
4      Fourth     City4    men,women
```

**Case 3:** I want to display person those who are looking for **women**. The required output should be,

```
ID    NickName    City    LookingFor
------------------------------------
1      Second     City2     women
3      Third      City3    men,women
4      Fourth     City4    men,women
```

I have tried using below code. But all the above case is not coming corrrectly.

```
SELECT * FROM `table_name WHERE LookingFor LIKE  '%men,women%';
```

Comment: I know I may be flayed for saying this but please try to normalize your table data, move the Gender data to a separate table and use a join table to store User_LookingFor data. Agreed there is the overhead of Join when you are generating views but it will save you a great deal of pain in the future. What if you want to add "Queer/Transgender" to the LookingFor field and subsequently give users an option to add that as well to their profile? An even better option would be to use JSON datatype for that field if you are using MySQL 5.8+ or NoSQL if you want to skip the 'Join' headache.

Comment: What is your definition of the word "and" ?

Answer (score 2):

You can remove the where clause if someone is looking for men and women, since all record will be fetch, regardless of the gender.

```
SELECT * FROM table_name
```

If you're looking for a specific gender

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name
WHERE CONCAT(',', LookingFor, ',') LIKE '%,men,%';

SELECT *
FROM table_name
WHERE CONCAT(',', LookingFor, ',') LIKE '%,women,%';
```

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen indeed, check case 1 desired output

Comment: I gave the upvote after editing.  If you want `LIKE` to work, you need to do more work than to just compare `%men%` or `%women%` (in fact `%men%` would match both men and women).

Comment: Ah true, I didn't pay enough attention concerning (wo)men. @TimBiegeleisen did the job, thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Use [FIND_IN_SET](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function, to search for a substring within a comma-separate string. Here are the applicable queries, for various cases you mentioned:

If looking for Men Or Women:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name 
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('men', LookingFor) > 0 OR  
      FIND_IN_SET('women', LookingFor) > 0;
```

If looking for Men:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name 
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('men', LookingFor) > 0;
```

If looking for Women:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name 
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('women', LookingFor) > 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

We can try using `FIND_IN_SET` here, e.g. the query for cities having both men and women:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('men', LookingFor) > 0 AND FIND_IN_SET('women', LookingFor) > 0;
```

But, it is really a bad practice to store CSV data in your tables.  You should instead *normalize* your data and store one gender per record.

Trivially, if the `LookingFor` column only ever stores up to two genders, *and* you maintain an alphabetical sort, you could check directly for the combined CSV value, e.g.

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE LookingFor = 'men,women';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below for three of your cases:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE LookingFor LIKE  '%men%' 

SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE LookingFor LIKE  'men%' 

SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE LookingFor LIKE LookingFor LIKE  '%women%'
```

Answer (score 0):

try doing in php

```
 <?php 


    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","test");
    $sql="SELECT * FROM `stack`";
    $resultset=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultset))
    {

        check($row);

    }

    function check($row)
    {
         if(strpos(strtolower($row['LookingFor']),'men') !== false)
         {
            echo " are you looking for men</br>";
            print($row['LookingFor']);
            echo "</br>";

        }elseif(strpos(strtolower($row['LookingFor']),'women') !== false){

           echo " are you looking for women</br>";
            print($row['LookingFor']);
            echo "</br>";


    }


    }
    ?>
```

Comment: He might not be using php for his application. filtering data upstream is often prefered.